# Display random value from multi-value field in Views

Tags: 7, views, media, entities

I have an image field that allows unlimited values, and I need to use Views to display a random image from a node's image field. The View should display a random image from that node's field each time the page is reloaded. How can this be accomplished?

Example:

- On page load, display image "1" from Node A's multi-image field.
- Reload page, display image "3" from Node A's multi-image field.
- Reload page, display image "2" from Node A's multi-image field.
- Reload page, display image "3" from Node A's multi-image field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-querying with Views for information you already have is excessive. I think a better option is to use something like
 [Single Image Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_image) which can display a random value from a multivalue image field.

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I was looking for! I used Single Image as the field formatter and left that field's "Image to display" value blank. I also had to leave the "Display __ Values" in the "Multiple field settings" for the image field blank, essentially instructing the field to display all of the values for that field.